# Please explain Jordi's answer. Exercise 4 on p.45 in Exercises 2C in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 4 on p.45 in Exercises 2C in this book.

> Exercise 4
> Give an example of a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ such that $$\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}=\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3k,3k+1].$$

I guessed we can use the result of [Exercise 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674947/384082) to solve Exercise 4.
But I don't know how to use the result of [Exercise 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674947/384082) to solve Exercise 4.

I found [Jordi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442915/384082) and I tried to understand his answer.
But I was not able to understand it.

Please explain [Jordi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442915/384082).

By the way, Exercise 4 is in section 2C and Lebesgue measure is in section 2D.
So, I think the author doesn't expect a solution that uses Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{S}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure defined on  Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$.

Now, let $D$ be any fixed countable infinite subset of $[0,1]$. Let $\nu$ be the measure defined by $\nu(\{p\}) = 3$, for all $p\in D$ and $\nu(A)=0$, for all $A \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $A \cap D= \emptyset$.

Define $\mu= \lambda + \nu $. It is easy to see that $\mu$ is a measure defined on  Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$.

It is also easy to see that

1. $\mu(X)= +\infty$;
2. for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S} \text{ and }\#(E\cap D)=k \}=[3k,3k+1]$.

It follows immediately that $\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}=\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3k,3k+1]$.

Comment: Ramiro, Thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Ramiro, I don't downvote. Someone downvoted. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the following Example 2.55 on p.42 in section 2C in the book to solve Exercise 4.

> - Suppose $X$ is a set, $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and $w:X\to [0,\infty]$ is a function.
>   Define a measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{S})$ by $$\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} w(x)$$ for $E\in\mathcal{S}.$ [Here the sum is defined as the supremum of all finite subsums $\sum_{x\in D} w(x)$ as $D$ ranges over all finite subsets of $E.$]

My solution is here:

> Let $X:=\mathbb{Q}.$
> Let $\mathcal{S}:=2^X.$
> Let $w:X\to [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $w(x):=\begin{cases} 
> 3 & \text{ if }x\in X\setminus\mathbb{Z}^+,\\
> \frac{1}{2^x}, & \text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Z}^+
> \end{cases}.$
> Let $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $\mu(E
> ):=\sum_{x\in E} w(x)$ for $E\in\mathcal{S}.$
> Then, by Example 2.55 on p.42 in section 2C in the book, $\mu$ is really a measure on $(X,\mathcal{S}).$
> Let $E\in\mathcal{S}.$
> If $E$ contains infinitely many elements of $X\setminus\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $\mu(E)=\infty.$
> If $E$ contains $k$ elements of $X\setminus\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $\mu(E)=3k+\sum_{x\in E\cap\mathbb{Z}^+} w(x)\in [3k,3k+1].$
> So, $$\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}\subset\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3k,3k+1].$$
> $\mu(X)=\infty$.
> Let $a\in [3k,3k+1].$
> Then, $a-3k\in [0,1].$
> Then we can write $a-3k=a_1w(1)+a_2w(2)+\cdots$, where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\dots\}.$
> Let $E_{a-3k}:=\{i\in\{1,2,\dots\}:a_i=1\}.$
> Then, $E_{a-3k}\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mu(E_{a-3k})=a-3k.$
> Let $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{E':=\{\frac{1}{3k+1},\frac{2}{3k+1},\dots,\frac{3k}{3k+1}\}.}$
> Let $E':=\{\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{2}{k+1},\dots,\frac{k}{k+1}\}.$
> Then, $\mu(E')=3k$.
> Therefore, $\mu(E'\cup E_{a-3k})=\mu(E')+\mu(E_{a-3k})=3k + (a-3k)=a.$
> So, $$\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}\supset\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3k,3k+1].$$

Comment: Your solution is correct. However, using the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ is a simpler way to get the "continuous" part, then all we need is to add a countable collection of atoms, each of them with measure 3. 

By the way,  you wrote  $E':=\{\frac{1}{3k+1},\frac{2}{3k+1},\dots,\frac{3k}{3k+1}\}$. I think you meant   
 $E':=\{\frac{1}{3k+1},\frac{2}{3k+1},\dots,\frac{k}{3k+1}\}$ (just $k$ elements, to get $\mu(E')=3k$).

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you very much for your comment and correction.